# Does RAID1 also checks for corruption?

Tags: raid, ntfs, raid1, mirroring, data-integrity

I have two 1.5 TB disks, and I don't trust both of them because of weird noises and bad clusters.

I was wondering if I put them in a software RAID1 array (mirrored volume in Win7) it will write my data to both disks, but will it also make sure that when reading data, the data is identical on both disks? Because then I can still reliable use these broken disks, without worrying about data corruption.

Comment: If the disk is broken, then get rid of it.  Disks just get worse.  If you aren't sure, run badblocks against it, and then check your SMART values.

Comment: You can't smush together two failing drives into a RAID mirror and call it 'one working drive'. It's like solving the problem of having one ticking time bomb by setting a *second* ticking time bomb next to it. Get new disks, move what remains of your data, chuck the bad disks. Period.

Answer (score 2):

"They are making wierd noises and have bad clusters".  Why after saying this would you ever think you could trust these disks even if RAID levels could do something? Disks/storage is cheap and as previously mentioned, drive issues only get worse. Re-read what you have asked and just replace the drives where needed.